# Convert unicode to Chinese char inside JSON?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I've some data in database (sql server 2008) in JSON format with unicode like this:

```
{"PCode":"999999","Code":"123","effect":"\u4e2d\u6587\u5b57\u6e2c\u8a66"}
```

`\u4e2d\u6587\u5b57\u6e2c\u8a66` are Chinese characters, how can I retieve the data in Chinese characters?

Comment: once chinese characters converted into hexadecimal...you can not convert them back. your column should support unicode. I think you are using varchar for storing data instead of Nvarchar.

Comment: What is the column data type and SQL Server version? Usually `OPENJSON` call is enough.

Comment: @DaleK the answer i've tried

Comment: @hkguile unless you are actually answering your own question, you need to add that to your question and remove the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer:**

It seems you use SQL Server 2008 (where JSON support is not available), so one possible aproach is to parse the unicode sequence as XML. Note, that XML doesn't use `\u` notation, so you need to transform this JSON text using XML character reference `&#x[0-9a-fA-F];`:

T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @text nvarchar(max)
SET @text = N'\u4e2d\u6587\u5b57\u6e2c\u8a66'

DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml = N'<x>' + STUFF(REPLACE(@text, N'\u', N';&#x'), 1, 1, N'') + N';</x>'
SELECT @xml.value('(/x)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [ChineseText]
```

Result:

```
ChineseText
-----------
中文字測試
```

Note, that from SQL Server 2016, you can easily parse the JSON using `JSON_VALUE()`.

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(CONCAT(N'["', @text, N'"]'), '$[0]') AS [ChineseText]
```

**Update:**

If the JSON has additional characters, you need to split the JSON content using XML and `\u` as separator:

```
DECLARE @text nvarchar(max)
SET @text = N'\u4e2deng\u6587eng\u5b57234\u6e2c\u8a66'

DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml = CONCAT(STUFF(REPLACE(@text, N'\u', N'</x><x>'), 1, 4, N''), N'</x>')
SELECT 
   CONVERT(xml, N'<x>&#x' + LEFT(t.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 4) + N';</x>').value('(/x)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 
   STUFF(t.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 4, N'')
FROM @xml.nodes('/x') AS x(t)
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Result:

```
中eng文eng字234測試
```

Comment: seems like i don't have concat funtion

Comment: @hkguile, you may use `+` concatenation operator.

Comment: but still need to hand if some number/eng inside the string e.g  \u4e2deng\u6587eng\u5b57234\u6e2c\u8a66

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Answer (score 0):

Any better practice?

```
DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @stringToSplit NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))

set @stringToSplit = '\u4e2d\u6587\u5b57\u6e2c\u8a66'

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX('\u', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX('\u', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  IF @name <> ''
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT NCHAR( CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY,@name, 2) ) )
  END

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos),2,LEN(@stringToSplit))
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT NCHAR( CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY,@stringToSplit, 2) ) )

 select * from @returnList
```